# How to set dateformat dynamically (uib-datepicker-popup="$ctrl.format")

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, momentjs

Here is the code which I am writing:

```
moment.locale(abp.localization.currentLanguage.name);          
ctrl.dateformat = {
format: moment()._locale._longDateFormat['L']                
}
console.log(ctrl.dateformat.format);
Console Output: DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY or YYYY/MM/DD
```

I get the date format based on current language, but I am unable to set the 
format to `uib-datepicker-popup`

At this moment the format set static like `uib-datepicker-popup=DD/MM/YYYY`

I try to pass this data to datepicker like this `uib-datepicker-popup=$ctrl.dateformat.format`.

[After Date Select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUE8w.png)

Could you please help us.

Comment: Could you please give any soloution

Comment: try with `new Date(moment()._locale._longDateFormat['L'])`

Comment: @ Ashish Choudhary 
My console Output is correct. My question is how to set this format to 
uib-datepicker-popup?

Comment: Answer: My console output date format does not support uib-datepicker-popup. uib-datepicker-popup expect format like (dd/MM/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy or yyyy/MM/dd). It is working now. Based on the culture I am able to change the date format